# ASP.NET MVC 4 windows authentication not working when changing the ConnectionString although both have the same username/password

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

In our ASP.NET MVC 4 application we are using Windows authentication for an InternAt website. The app has an admin page where user can search active directory for a domain user, and assign user a role. The Roles are custom Roles and not the Windows groups (Client did not want to create Windows groups just for this app). Before deploying the app from dev server to the production I created a user using code as ProductionDomain\myProsuctionWinLogin (I am also in the production server domain). After deployment, I created an admin user (Windows login) for a user on production who would be managing the app.

The Dev server is on our company domain and the production server is in our client's company domain.

When we deployed the database from our company server to our client's server (production) my windows login from our company domain also got migrated to the production server.

We are allowed to make a copy of the production database to our company server for testing/fixes purposes. Note that database login and password for both the test server and production server is exactly the same and we have tested that the same login/password works on the test server when we directly login to the database via SQL Server Management Studio.

But when we copy the database to our server and change the connection string in the web.config by just changing the production server name to our test server the app gives the following error: "Unauthorized Access".

On the other hand if we change the server name to our dev server where the app was originally developed and where we have the old database with the same SQL login/password, the application starts working. Following is connection string in the web.config (with fictional names for privacy. The connection string is exactly the same for production, dev and test servers with the exception of the server name of course):

```
<add connectionString="Server=ProdServer;Database=myDb;User ID=aUserID;Password=aUSerPassword" name="AonnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have verified that on all three servers the aspnet_Roles table has the exact same roles and my windows login name (from my company domain) is also there in the table aspnet_Users on all three servers.

Can someone please explain why the app works on dev server but not on the test server and what is the solution?

Thanks..Nam

Comment: are you granting access to the account on the production server to the  database you have copied over?

Comment: are the production web server and sql server on different machines?

Comment: I am curious about the "Unauthorized Access" error. If it was related to the user name I would have expected "Login failed". Do you have any more information about the error?

Comment: @Gavin,1: The SQL Server user account and password are exactly the same on all three servers and have the db_owner access to the database with the same name on all the servers. Moreover, I can login to any of the three servers using that SQL user login. 2: The production web server and SQL server are on the same machine - same is true for the dev and test environment. 3. In regard to more information about the error - how can I get that? I looked into the Even Viewer, there is no related information there.

Comment: Please supply the full error message,

Comment: Maybe we are barking up the wrong tree, could it be that asp.net cannot access some part of the file system, eg the location of the temporary asp.net files? As far as where can you get the error where are you seeing the Unauthorized Access error?

Answer (score 0):

Check the sql server login is correctly configured!

Comment: please see my comments above.